# Assignment to "in" mode parameter not allowed

Tags: function, record, ada

It seems that I can't put a record field as a parameter?

```
joueurActuel.c1 := predColonne(joueurActuel.c1);
```

The function:

```
function predColonne (c : T_Colonne) return T_Colonne;
```

where `T_Colonne` is a subtype of `Positive`.

`joueurActuel` is an `in` parameter (`joueurActuel : in T_Joueur;`) of a function containing the assignment above. `T_Joueur` is a record.

Comment: "It seems" is not a helpful specification of a problem. What error message do you get and when? Compile-time / run-time? What's the declaration of `joueurActuel` and the definition of its type?

Comment: It's a compilation error, assignment to “in” mode parameter not allowed.

Comment: I try to use a temporary variable like this :

`tempc := predColonne(joueurActuel.c1);
joueurActuel.c1 := tempc;`

It change nothing, I still have the same error on the second line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. A formal parameter of mode `in` is a constant view; it cannot be updated within the subprogram body. A constant cannot be the target of an assignment operation. See [section 3.3 od Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-3.html), paragraphs 13, 15, 17 and 25 in particular.

So, either you have to store the result of `predColonne(joueurActuel.c1)` in a local variable, or change `joueurActuel` into an `in out` parameter if it's correct from the business logic point of view.

Answer (score 5):

The `in` mode in `joueurActuel : in T_Joueur;` is a guarantee you have given to the compiler that you will not update or modify `joueurActuel` in any way within the procedure where you declared this formal parameter. The fact that it's a record is nothing to do with the problem.

`joueurActuel.c1 := predColonne(joueurActuel.c1);` is an attempt to modify `joueurActuel`, despite the guarantee.

The compiler, correctly, rejects it.

If this is really what you want to do, then mode `in out` will allow it, but first ask yourself it there is a better design. Does the rest of the program need to see the change? If so, then `in out` is acceptable. Otherwise, copying it to a local variable as Ondrej suggested it, and only modifying the local copy, will work.